# Spring JMS Producer and Consumer interaction

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-jms

How can i determine if the consumer already received the message from the producer or how can i notify the producer that the message have already been sent/consumed in Spring JMS?

Comment: If you just want to notify then you can use AUTO_ACK mode but if you need redelivery in case of exception then you should use transacted="true". This has already been asked at SO. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9095471/getting-a-simple-spring-jms-client-acknowledge-to-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use request/reply by using `org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.sendAndReceive(...)` on the producer side and on the consumer side the MessageListener method set in the container must return a value.

or make your producer subscribing to `ActiveMQ.Advisory.MessageConsumed.Queue` to be notified when the message is consumed by having access to some properties like `orignalMessageId`, take a look here http://activemq.apache.org/advisory-message.html

you can use it like this :

```
            Destination advisoryDestination = org.apache.activemq.advisory.AdvisorySupport
                    .getMessageConsumedAdvisoryTopic(session.createQueue("yourQueue"));
            MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(advisoryDestination);
            consumer.setMessageListener(new MessageListener() {
                @Override
                public void onMessage(Message msg) {
                    System.out.println(msg);
                    System.out.println(((ActiveMQMessage) msg).getMessageId());
                    ActiveMQMessage aMsg = (ActiveMQMessage) ((ActiveMQMessage) msg).getDataStructure();
                    System.out.println(aMsg.getMessageId());
                }
            });
```