# Configuring sessionAcknowledgeMode in DefaultMessageListenerContainer

Tags: spring-boot, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I have a setup where I have to read a message from a queue in an ActiveMQ broker. Once the message is read I have to do a long-running operation on the message.

Due to this long-running operation on the message I want to acknowledge the message as soon as possible so the resources on the broker are released. The plan would be to execute the following steps once a message is received:

1. Get message from ActiveMQ
2. Insert message into DB
3. Acknowledge message
4. Do some long-running operation with the message

I've read about JMS and the different acknowledge modes, so before even trying to do that I decided to set up an application where I could try the different modes to understand how they are processes, unfortunately I cannot seem to get my desired output.

Following the information in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/10188078 as well as https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/listener/DefaultMessageListenerContainer.html I thought that by using AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE the message would be acknowledged before my listener is even called, but if I throw an exception in the listener the message is redelivered.

I've tried both with and without setting the setSessionTransacted to true, but in both cases I get the same output. The message is redelivered when an exception is thrown in the JmsListener.

Configuration of JMS

```
    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory =
                new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(jmsConfig.getBrokerUrl());

        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsTemplate jmstemplate(){
        JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate();
        jmsTemplate.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        //jmsTemplate.setSessionTransacted(true);
        jmsTemplate.setDefaultDestinationName( jmsConfig.getQueueIn() );
        return jmsTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactoryxxxx(
                    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
            DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {

        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        //factory.setConcurrency("1");
        factory.setSessionTransacted(true);

        configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
        return factory;
    }
```

JmsListener

```
@JmsListener(destination = "B1Q1", containerFactory = "jmsListenerContainerFactoryxxxx")
public  void receiveMessage(Message message) {
    try {
        TextMessage m = (TextMessage) message;
        String messageText = m.getText();

        int retryNum = message.getIntProperty("JMSXDeliveryCount");
        long s = message.getLongProperty("JMSTimestamp");

        Date d = new Date( s );

        String dbText = String.format("Retry %d. Message: %s", retryNum, messageText);

        if ( messageText.toLowerCase().contains("exception") ) {
            logger.info("Creating exception for retry: {}", retryNum);
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        logger.error("Exception!!", e);
    }
}
```

How should I change the code so that the message is not redelivered when an exception is thrown?

Going back to my application where I would be inserting the message into the DB. How could I acknowledge the message in by JmsListener after the message is inserted in the DB but before executing the long-running task?

Comment: Setting sessionTransacted to false on the DefaultMessageListenerContainer should not redeliver the message if the listener throws an exception.
Are you sure you're setting sessionTransacted to false on the DefaultMessageListenerContainer, and not on the JmsTemplate?

Comment: The problem was in the `JmsListenerContainerFactory` method. After setting the session transaction  with `factory.setSessionTransacted(false)` I'm calling `configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);` which overrides the value to `true`. I simply changes the order of those calls and now the message is no longer delivered when an exception is thrown in the `JmsListener`

Comment: Brilliant!
Please consider adding this as an answer & mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to be able to use `AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE` or `CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE` I had to call `factory.setSessionTransacted(false)` after configuring the factory.

Calling `configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory)` overrides the value of `sessionTransacted`, in my case it was setting it to `true` which rendered `AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE` or `CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE` ineffective. Here's the relevant code of `DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer.java`:

```
public void configure(DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory, ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
...
...
        if (this.transactionManager != null) {
            factory.setTransactionManager(this.transactionManager);
        } else {
            factory.setSessionTransacted(true);
        }
...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
          factory.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Tibjms.EXPLICIT_CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
          //factory.setSessionTransacted(false);// here it’s  not working
          factory.setTaskExecutor(new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor("KDBMessageListener-"));
          configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
          factory.setSessionTransacted(false); //post configure ,session transacted is working
```