I am trying to manually Acknowledge the message after a successful processing
I'm currently using Spring Boot version 3.3.0 and Java 21.
And I'm facing an issue with setting the SessionAcknowledgeMode to Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE. I am trying to manually Acknowledge the message after a successful processing. So, to achieve that, I am trying to set SessionAcknowledgeMode to Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE but it is not working. My Listener is Auto acknowledging the messages. Despite trying multiple approaches, it isn't functioning as expected. Any guidance or solutions would be greatly appreciated!
pom.xml file:
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

My Listener:
@JmsListener(destination = "test.queue", containerFactory = "jmsListenerContainerFactory")
    public void configure(Message message) {
        try {
            TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
            log.info("Received message {} ", textMessage.getText());
            // Commenting out the acknowledgement
            //message.acknowledge();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Message processing failed.");
        }
    }

I've commented out message.acknowledge(); in the code, but the messages are still being removed from ActiveMQ.
This is my Configuration:
@Bean
JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> jmsListenerContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    SimpleJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    factory.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    factory.setSessionTransacted(false);
    return factory;
}

When I test using a manual code snippet, it behaves as expected—messages are not deleted from the queue if I don't acknowledge them.
ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("test", "test",
                    "tcp://localhost:61616");

            try (Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection()) {
                connection.start();
                try (Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE)) {
                    Queue queue = session.createQueue("bharad.test");
                    MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(queue);
                    while (true) {
                        Message message = consumer.receive(1000);
                        if (message != null) {
                            TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
                            System.out.println("Received message: " + textMessage.getText());
                            message.acknowledge();
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("No messages in queue");
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }


This seems similar to the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57129725/configuring-sessionacknowledgemode-in-defaultmessagelistenercontainer Try to see if that solution can help you.

Nope. It didn't work.

The answer is actually written in the docs for SimpleJmsListenerContainer:

Note that this container exposes standard JMS behavior for the default "AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE" mode: that is, automatic message acknowledgment after listener execution, with no redelivery in case of a user exception thrown but potential redelivery in case of the JVM dying during listener execution
For a different style of MessageListener handling, through looped MessageConsumer.receive() calls that also allow for transactional reception of messages (registering them with XA transactions), see DefaultMessageListenerContainer.

So it literally only provides AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE behavior and is not configurable otherwise.
If you want to configure other behaviour, use DefaultMessageListenerContainer
